# Mysterious Ruby Block behavior: &block vs. {block.call}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

When writing a helper for printing javascript that can be used from both other helpers and views, I stumbled upon the following problem:

```
def javascript(print_tag = false, &block)
  content_for(:javascript) do
    if print_tag
      javascript_tag(&block)          # does not work
      javascript_tag { block.call }   # does work 
    else
      capture(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

This helper should be called with `javascript { "alert('hurray'); }`.

In the first alternative - which I expected to work - the [Rails javascript_tag helper](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag) renders an empty `<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[  //]]> </script>` tag.

The second alternative, however, works as expected.

What's going on there? How can that be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you are doing this on your views, right?

```
<%= javascript { "alert('hurray');" } %>
```

But for `content_tag(&block)` to work, you should call `javascript` the way `content_tag` is intended to be used in views, which is:

```
<% javascript do %>
  alert('hurray');
<% end %>
```

`content_tag`'s behavior is different depending on where it's called from, see the function `block_called_from_erb?` in the source code. In the first case this function returns `true` because the block does come from an erb (and then it's `concat`ed, you don't want that!), in the second returns `false` (you re-created the block from scratch) and `content_tag` simply returns the string content, which is what you want.

```
# ./action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb
tag = content_tag(:script, javascript_cdata_section(content), html_options.merge(:type => Mime::JS))
if block_called_from_erb?(block)
  concat(tag)
else
  tag
end
```

Comment: Ough... what a tricky implementation! Actually I am using Haml:     `- javascript(true) { fire_flash } if flash_message.present?` and I don't want to write that in 4 lines if it is fine in 1 line. But, thank you very much!